# Groovy syntax for enter/exit block

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to define a block/environment with custom open and close methods? Currently, I have:

```
script {
   withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '...', usernameVariable: 'CONFIG_USER', passwordVariable: 'CONFIG_PASS')]) {
      def sql = Sql.newInstance("...", CONFIG_USER, CONFIG_PASS, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
      sql.rows("SELECT * FROM visualization").each { row ->
         println "row ${row.branch}"
      }
      sql.close()
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
with sqlConnection() { sql ->
   sql.rows("SELECT * FROM visualization").each { row ->
      println "row ${row.branch}"
   }
}
```

Where it automatically opens/closes the connection accordingly. I am new to Groovy, so it's the syntax I'm concerned about. In Python I would do this using an object `__enter__`/`__exit__`.

Comment: Can you use [withInstance](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withInstance-java.lang.String-groovy.lang.Closure-) instead of `newInstance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a new method `sqlConnection()` that does the `withCredentials` part?

You can use a closure parameter to do something before or after something else.

```
def sqlConnection(Closure withSqlClosure) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '...', usernameVariable: 'CONFIG_USER', passwordVariable: 'CONFIG_PASS')]) {
        Sql.newInstance("...", CONFIG_USER, CONFIG_PASS, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").withCloseable {sql ->
            withSqlClosure(sql)
        }
    }
}
```

Can be used like this

```
sqlConnection() { sql ->
    sql.rows("SELECT * FROM visualization").each { row ->
        println "row ${row.branch}"
    }
}
```

So everything before the call to the closure (`withSqlClosure(sql)`) corresponds to `__enter__` everything after the call is your `__exit__`. Note that you will need to lookout for exceptions. Usually you will want to wrap the closure call in a `try { ... } finally { ... }` Statement. Here I used `withCloseable` which does that for us (assuming `Sql.newInstance` returns a `Closeable`).

To aid your IDE and enable `@CompileStatic` you should also add a `@ClosureParams`

```
def sqlConnection(
        @ClosureParams(value = groovy.transform.stc.SimpleType,
                options = ["your.sql.type"]) Closure withSqlClosure) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '...', usernameVariable: 'CONFIG_USER', passwordVariable: 'CONFIG_PASS')]) {
        Sql.newInstance("...", CONFIG_USER, CONFIG_PASS, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").withCloseable {sql ->
            withSqlClosure(sql)
        }
    }
}
```

Here `your.sql.type` is the return type of `Sql.newInstance`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Closure was exactly what I was looking for!